# JQuery UI Button swallows span

Tags: jquery-ui, button

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="scheduleNav">
    <a id="btnPrevDate" href="#" class="ui-button-icon-only" />
    <span id="currentDate">???</span>
    <a id="btnNextDate" href="#" class="ui-button-icon-only" />
</div>
```

And the following javascript:

```
var rightNow = new Date(); //   Default to today
var dd = rightNow.getDate();
var mm = rightNow.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = rightNow.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd; }
if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm; }
var today = (mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy);
var prev = $('#btnPrevDate').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-seek-prev"} });
var next = $('#btnNextDate').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-seek-next"} });
var currentDate = $('#currentDate');
currentDate.text(today);
```

The jsbin is here: http://jsbin.com/AgiSICE/1/edit?html,js,output

How can I prevent the first anchor from swallowing the span?

Comment: The example you provided has multiple errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I closed your first anchor by adding  instead of  it worked for me.

Comment: sorry, <a></a> vs <a blah blah /> here's a jsbin link http://jsbin.com/eYITEZo/1/edit

Comment: Any explanation on that btw? Why using the closed version of the element doesn't work?